# Sending Messages To a ListBox

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to add some strings to a listbox.Is this possible to send a message from a function to add string into a listbox?

Comment: SendMessage Function didn't work.

Comment: Check whether you have the correct handle to the control, have you tried the first approach?

Comment: I knew the first approach....
SendMessage(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_LIST1), LB_INSERTSTRING, Index, (LPARAM)lpBuffer);
when i use the above i got error like there's no suitable conversion available from Cstring to LPARM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the correct code. That's as follows....

```
LPTSTR  lpBuffer = m_WindowTitle.GetBuffer( );
HWND listHWnd = ::GetDlgItem(AfxGetMainWnd()->m_hWnd, IDC_LIST1);
SendMessage(listHWnd, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)lpBuffer);
m_WindowTitle.ReleaseBuffer ( );
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a member variable for the listbox and say `m_ctrlListBox.AddString` or

```
CListBox *pMyList = (CListBox *) GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1);
pMyList->AddString("My String");
```

If you want to send message then you can try these

```
SendMessage(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_LIST1), LB_INSERTSTRING, Index, (LPARAM)lpBuffer);

SendMessage(hWnd, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)lpBuffer);
```

**Example:**

```
    CString myString("Hi");
    LPTSTR  lpBuffer = myString.GetBuffer(myString.GetLength());

    CWnd* cw= GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1);
    ::SendMessage(cw->GetSafeHwnd(), LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)lpBuffer);
    myString.ReleaseBuffer ( );
```